# shm_unlink from the shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shared-memory

I have a program that creates a shared memory object with `shm_open` that I'm working on. It tries to release the object with `shm_unlink`, but sometimes a programming error will cause it to crash before it can make that call. In that case, I need to unlink the shared memory object "by hand," and I'd like to be able to do it in a normal shell, without writing any C code -- i.e. with normal Linux utilities.

Can it be done? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793992) seems to say that using `unlink(1)` on `/dev/shm/path_passed_to_shm_open`, but the manpages aren't clear.

Comment: Try unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com for non-programming questions.

Comment: @Barmar This seems to me to be a very similar question to the one that I linked. It could be rephrased as "Can shared memory objects created via `shm_open` be removed by unlinking the corresponding file in `/dev/shm/`?" but I think that's a very minor difference. I don't think this question ceases to be programming related just because I'd rather re-use existing \*nix tools than reinvent the wheel. I don't think the vote close reason fits because `shm_open` is most definitely "primarily used for programming," not a "general purpose computing tool."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlinking the file in `/dev/shm` will delete the shared memory object if no other process has the object mapped.

Unlike SYSV shared memory, which is implemented in the Kernel, POSIX shared memory objects are simply "files in disguise".

When you call shm_open and mmap, you can see the following in the process process map (using `pmap -X`):

```
 Address Perm   Offset Device   Inode Mapping
b7737000 r--s 00000000  00:0d 2267945 test_object
```

The device major and minor number correspond to the tmpfs mounted at `/dev/shm` (some systems mount this at /run, and then symlink `/dev/shm` to `/run/shm`).

A listing of the folder will show the same inode number:

```
$ ls -li /dev/shm/
2267945 -rw------- 1 mikel mikel 1 Apr 14 13:36 test_object
```

Like any other inode, the space will be freed when all references are removed. If we close the only program referencing this we see:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep Shmem
Shmem:               700 kB
```

Once we remove the last reference (created in `/dev/shm`), the space will be freed:

```
$ rm /dev/shm/test_object
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep Shmem
Shmem:               696 kB
```

If you're curious, you can look at the corresponding files in the glibc sources. [shm_directory.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/shm-directory.c;hb=HEAD) and [shm_directory.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/shm-directory.h;hb=HEAD) generate the filename as `/dev/your_shm_name`. The implementations [shm_open](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/shm_open.c;hb=HEAD) and [shm_unlink](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/posix/shm_unlink.c;hb=HEAD) simply open and unlink this file. So it should be easy to see that `rm /dev/shm/your_shm_name` performs the same operation,

Comment: Fantastic answer. I'll wait a little bit to accept in case anyone else wants to add something, but this is great.